# MQTT with PAHO C Library

Tags: c, mqtt, paho

Im trying to test a simple windows script (.exe) to connect to a local mosquitto broker using the PAHO C client, but I'm stuck to do so.

First I follow the instructions here to install the paho.mqtt.c library:

[github link](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp)

I scroll down to 'Windows' section and follow the rules.
Using Cmake GUI I was able to configure and generate (visual studio 2015) the paho.mqtt.c lib.

Using this command:
`cmake --build build --target install`

I found another directory/project is created under name of 'Eclipse PAHO C'
Now I don't know where is the project or .exe file to run, I just found a lot of c files and headers.

It's the first time for me to build an application using cmake, also the documentation for setting up the mqtt C library on OS windows is little complex.

Im trying to test a simple windows script (.exe) to connect to a local mosquitto broker using the PAHO C client, but I'm stuck to do so.

First I follow the instructions here to install the paho.mqtt.c library:

[paho mqtt cpp github link](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.cpp)

I scroll down to 'Windows' section and follow the rules.
Using Cmake GUI I was able to configure and generate (visual studio 2015) the paho.mqtt.c lib.

Using this command:
`cmake --build build --target install`

I found another directory/project is created under name of 'Eclipse PAHO C'
Now I don't know where is the project or .exe file to run, I just found a lot of c files and headers.

It's the first time for me to build an application using cmake, also the documentation for setting up the mqtt C library on OS windows is little complex.

Edit::

To be more specific, here it's what I do in cmake GUI, what to do next to build my application is not clear.

[image: CMake GUI build configuratios]

I have tried to go to sample/test folders and build a sample application using visual studio but always ends up with an error while running the .exe file.

[image: application run error]

Answer (score 0):

There is no "script" or executable. Paho C is a library to allow you add a MQTT client to your own application.

There are some samples, under the `src\samples` directory that contain some concrete examples that can be complied to executables, but these will only be built if the cmake variable `PAHO_BUILD_SAMPLES` is set to `TRUE` (it defaults to `FALSE`)

You will need to add `-DPAHO_BUILD_SAMPLES=ON` to the cmake line

Comment: Thanks, but the samples folder contains bunch of c files not a project structure how can i build my application assuming that the generator is visual studio 2015?

Comment: I have edited the question for more specific info